# Android - Ugly box when I use StateListDrawable

Tags: android, selector

I am using the following code -

```
StateListDrawable states2 = new StateListDrawable();
    states2.clearColorFilter();
    states2.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.title_search_alt));
    //states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
    //    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.title_search_alt));
    states2.addState(new int[] { },
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.inbox));
    ib2.setImageDrawable(states2);
```

However, when I run it, I get an ugly box surrounding my button. How do I get rid of it? I cannot use XML, so the solution has to be programmatic.

Edit:

looks like http://i56.tinypic.com/be645w.png
supposed to look like http://i56.tinypic.com/14mdlwl.png

Comment: edited the question with screenshot links. the latter is without using the StateListDrawable.

Comment: Ah, the system is adding a button background/border. You may need to provide a larger snippet to better show the context for this drawable... is it being used as a button background, etc?

Comment: yes its being used as the background for a button. does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set your background drawable for the button to something else or a null value with **android:background="@null"**

Comment: wow that worked!!! i did the following since I was doing it programmatically:
    button.setBackgroundResource(0);

Answer (score 1):

you can just use **button.setBackgroundDrawable(states2)**.